# How do i add a image overlay effect without setting the image height

Tags: jquery, html, css

How do i add a image overlay effect without setting the image height.
I have different size images on a slider while hover on those all images i need to have the text "view large image" with overlay effect, and its should pop up.
*note: Image heights are diffrent

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Not that this may be what you are looking for exactly...but should give you something to work off of....

https://jsfiddle.net/112y4mwt/

HTML

```
<div class="holder">
    <div class="overlay">View Larger</div>
    <img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/22/5d/20/225d20eaadbd3d7a3012c73e8b1119da.jpg" height="200px"/>
</div>

<div class="holder">
    <div class="overlay">View Larger</div>
    <img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/22/5d/20/225d20eaadbd3d7a3012c73e8b1119da.jpg" height="250px"/>
</div>

<div class="holder">
    <div class="overlay">View Larger</div>
    <img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/22/5d/20/225d20eaadbd3d7a3012c73e8b1119da.jpg" height="300px"/>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.holder {float:left; position:relative; overflow:hidden;}

.overlay {
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    width:100%; height:100%;
    text-align:center;
    background-color:rgba(0,0,0,.8);
    color:white;
}

.holder:hover .overlay {display:block;}
```